# How to copy a chart to different sheet using Apache POI(3.11)

Tags: excel, charts, apache-poi, java, excel-charts

I need to copy/move the chart to different existing/new sheet. Can we do this using POI?

I am able to move the chart within the same sheet but not to different sheets.